# cloudwatch alarm in Unchecked: Initial alarm creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created step scaling using Terraform.
Basically it monitors SQS queues based on number of messages i want to scale them.

1. I have executed the policy manually step up and step down. In both the cases it is working.

Now the problem is alarm is insufficient data. Hence the automatic scaling is not working.

Tried hitting the API for describe alarms i can see it is mentioned as Unchecked: Initial alarm creation.

Here is the snippet used for creating policy.

```html
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "agents-scale-up" {
  name                   = "stepuppolicy"
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  policy_type = "StepScaling"
  metric_aggregation_type = "Average"
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.test.name

step_adjustment {
  scaling_adjustment = 1
  metric_interval_lower_bound = 0
  metric_interval_upper_bound = 180
}
step_adjustment {
  scaling_adjustment = 5
  metric_interval_lower_bound = 180
  metric_interval_upper_bound = 360
}
}
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "agents-scale-down" {
  name                   = "stepdownpolicy"
  adjustment_type        = "ExactCapacity"
  policy_type = "StepScaling"
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.test.name
step_adjustment {
  scaling_adjustment = 1
  metric_interval_upper_bound = 0
}

}
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "memory-high" {
  alarm_name          = "scaleup"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "2"
  metric_name         = "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
  namespace           = "AWS/SQS"
  period              = "300"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "100"
  unit = "Count"
  alarm_description   = "scale-up"
  alarm_actions = [
    "${aws_autoscaling_policy.agents-scale-up.arn}"
  ]
  dimensions = {
    autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.test.name}"
    QueueName              = "queuename"
  }
}
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "memory-low" {
  alarm_name          = "scaledown"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "2"
  metric_name         = "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
  namespace           = "AWS/SQS"
  period              = "300"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "100"
  unit = "Count"
  alarm_description   = "scale-down"
  alarm_actions = [
    "${aws_autoscaling_policy.agents-scale-down.arn}"
  ]
  dimensions = {
    autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.test.name}"
    QueueName              = "queue-name"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i am able to fix it. Inside the dimensions block we have to specify only the queue name

```
dimensions = {
    QueueName              = "queuename"
  }
```

After this change i can alarm status clearly.